# Objective c: Where to save the files in folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a few files that needs to be saved for storing data such as player.json.

Right now I'm using

```
documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

However, it saves to the Documents directory in iOS and can be accessed from itunes.  Encrypting the file will also be very RAM consuming and on some earlier devices (iOS 5c), it slows the app down. So I was thinking about moving to a folder that normal users won't be able to access it.

What are the options here?  Should I create a folder in iOS for the files? Can anyone else access it?

Comment: Save in `tmp` folder, user will not be able to access this folder from itunes.

Comment: My question is if you save it in tmp folder. What circumstances would the files be deleted? Because I'm afraid tmp folder files will get clear out if something happens.

Comment: Can you just disable iTunes file sharing for your app completely?

Comment: Wow, @PartiallyFinite that is the answer I'm looking for.  Can you do that in objective C?

Comment: Try saving to the the cache directory. If it is only for internal program use. This way it won't be part iTunes file sharing even if you try to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable iTunes file sharing completely by adding this key to your Info.plist file in Xcode (click on the project, select the correct target in the left pane, and go to the **Info** tab in the top tab bar):

[image]

Then no files will be visible for your app at all when it is viewed in iTunes.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the Documents directory, there is the Library folder, which cannot be accessed by users through itunes

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = paths[0];
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, data in the NSLibraryDirectory can be lost from time to time, for example during certain major iOS updates Apple wipes the device's Library Directory (If I recall correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Read the iOS Data Storage Guideline
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html
If you don't want your files to be included in iTunes/iCloud backup either set 'do not backup' flag for them or move it in tmp folder.
Setting this flag also ensures that your files won't ever be purged automatically => you always have access to them.